# Can't install WinUSB on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: windows, iso, winusb

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my old computer.  I'm now trying to create a windows usb stick to install on a new computer I'm building.  When I add the repository

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
```

and I try to update, I get the following errors:

```
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found                         

    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then when I try:

```
   sudo apt-get install winusb
```

I get:

```
   E: Unable to locate package winusb
```

Can anyone help me find a solution?

Comment: The 404  "error" seems to suggest there are no package candidates on that repository for ubuntu willy.

Comment: I think you can follow the guide on WinUSB's GitHub[click here](https://github.com/slacka/WinUSB).
That is really helpful!

Answer (score 5):

To install in Ubuntu (16.04, 15.10, 15.04 and 14.04) or Linux Mint (17.x or 18) and derivatives. To add the PPA and install WinUSB, use the following commands:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
>
> sudo apt update
>
> apt install winusb

Comment: Silly question but How to run it? `winusb` command not found.

Comment: @LRDPRDX, have You installed it? :) Look for it in Programs Menu.

Comment: Of course I've installed it (using apt-get manager). I am using i3 wm. It's seems that command to run is `woeusb`.

Answer (score 3):

The Winusb package is *not* available from this PPA for Wily but there is a technique that worked well on my system to install it using the Saucy package. I have tested this under Trusty but it should also work under Wily:

Firstly download either 64bit or 32bit package from the PPA:

64bit:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb
```

32bit:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_i386.deb
```

Then install the file:

```
sudo dpkg -i winusb_1.0.11+saucy1*
```

You will see errors such as the following:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ sudo dpkg -i winusb_1.0.11+saucy1*
(Reading database ... 197467 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking winusb (1.0.11+saucy1) over (1.0.11+saucy1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of winusb:
 winusb depends on libwxbase2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1); however:
  Package libwxbase2.8-0 is not installed.
 winusb depends on libwxgtk2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1); however:
  Package libwxgtk2.8-0 is not installed.
 winusb depends on gksu; however:
  Package gksu is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package winusb (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 winusb
andrew@corinth:~$
```

Fix the errors:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

It is a very clumsy method (and certainly will not work for all deb packages!) but has certainly worked on my Trusty system and should also work on Wily:

[image]

**References:**

- [Install Winusb in Ubuntu 14.04](http://sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-winusb-ubuntu-14-04/)

Comment: Great news! If you are happy with the answer consider 'accepting' it: http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

There is a fork of winusb which works great in my Ubuntu Mate 18.04

It is [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install woeusb
```

You will find the launcher icon in the menu (or search in the menu).

Answer (score 1):

WinUSB won't work properly on Ubuntu 18.04.

Use woeUSB instead:

```
sudo apt-get install woeusb
```

Just restart the system after installation