# Win usb giving Exit code 256?

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount

```
Installation failed !
Exit code: 256
Log:
Formatting device...
Wait 3 seconds for block device nodes to populate...
mkfs.fat: warning - lowercase labels might not work properly with DOS or Windows
mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
Mounting...
Copying...
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_IN,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)
Processing archive: /media/winusb_iso_1491907065_2968/sources/install.wim
Extracting  1/Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efipulse
Everything is Ok
Size:       672640
Compressed: 2954401643
Installing grub...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installing grub.cfg...
Exiting...
Syncing...
/usr/bin/winusb: line 78:  6953 Terminated              while true; do
    sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
done
Cleaning...
/usr/bin/winusb: line 78:  9675 Terminated              while true; do
    sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
done
Unmounting and removing '/media/winusb_iso_1491907065_2968'...
Unmounting and removing '/media/winusb_target_1491907065_2968'...
```

Comment: Shouldn't you ask this on the windows forums?

Comment: am running it on ubuntu why i ask on windows forum

Comment: Checking the wiki of WinUSB, it seems to be owned by Microsoft. Or maybe there is a ubuntu managed package with the same name, in that case, I would be mistaken.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen, http://askubuntu.com/q/755053/527350